# Double click for navigation Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have the next problem with my app. I want to nav between 2 pages using a button. When I click the button the app should change the page pushing in the nav this new page. The problem is that when i click the button, only changes the ion-header of the page, not the content. I need to click twice .

I dont know where is the mistake in my code.

Here the button:

```
<button [navPush]="loginscreenpage" id="btnRegistro" style="border-right:1px solid white">Iniciar sesión</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI: You should really remove all that inline styles. and start using sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate through your pages in Ionic 2, I recommend using the `NavController` from `ionic-angular`

Here's an example.

**page1.ts**

```
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Page2Page} from '../page2/page2';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1'
})
export class Page1Page{

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

    itemTapped(){
        this.navCtrl.push(Page2Page);
    }
}
```

This will push your page with a 'back' button on the right corner of your app.

**page1.html**

```
// Your stuff
     <button (click)="itemTapped()">Iniciar sesión</button>
// End of your stuff
```

If your really want to change your root page, use the `setRoot` function from `NavController` : `this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page2Page)` instead of the `push` function.